# Best way to parallelize this loop in OpenMP

Tags: fortran, openmp, fortran77

I have the following loop which i have attempted to parallelized using OpenMP but i am seeing no performance improvement, can any one please suggest how to improve it.

```
thread = omp_get_max_threads ( )
chunk=jmaxm/thread
c$omp parallel shared (zetun,zetvn) private (i, j)
c$omp do schedule(DYNAMIC,chunk) ORDERED
    do j=2,jmaxm
        jm=j-1
        jp=j+1
             do i=2,imaxm
                if (rmask(i,j).eq.1.0)then
             im=i-1
             ip=i+1
             zetun(i,j)=
           +  (un(im,j,km)+un(ip,j,km)-2.*un(i,j,km))*recdx2
           +  + ((un(i,jp,km)-un(i,j,km))-
           +  (un(i,j,km)-un(i,jm,km)))*recdy2

             zetvn(i,j)=
           +  ((vn(ip,j,km)-vn(i,j,km))-
           +  (vn(i,j,km)-vn(im,j,km)))*recdx2
           +  + (vn(i,jp,km)+vn(i,jm,km)-2.*vn(i,j,km))*recdy2
              endif

        end do

    end do
 c$omp end do nowait
 c$omp end parallel
```

I am now adding the modified code it as follows, but still does not seem to make any improvement
MODIFIED CODE:

```
  c$omp parallel shared (zetun,zetvn) private (i,j,jm,jp,im,ip,km)

  c$omp do schedule(DYNAMIC,20) 
   do j=2,jmaxm
        jm=j-1
        jp=j+1
             do i=2,imaxm
                if (rmask(i,j).eq.1.0)then
             im=i-1
             ip=i+1
             zetun(i,j)=
           +  (un(im,j,km)+un(ip,j,km)-2.*un(i,j,km))*recdx2
           +  + ((un(i,jp,km)-un(i,j,km))-
           +  (un(i,j,km)-un(i,jm,km)))*recdy2

             zetvn(i,j)=
           +  ((vn(ip,j,km)-vn(i,j,km))-
           +  (vn(i,j,km)-vn(im,j,km)))*recdx2
           +  + (vn(i,jp,km)+vn(i,jm,km)-2.*vn(i,j,km))*recdy2
              endif

           end do

    end do
c$omp end do
c$omp end parallel
```

Answer (score 2):

The code is not valid. `jm`, `jp`, `im` and `ip` have to be private at least. Also, why you require `ordered`? It definitely slows it down. Also, hhy `schedule dynamic` with such a large chunk? Just use `static`.

Also, use some line indentation when coding, or at least when presenting your code to others.

Comment: I did as said but its taking even more time now, what about nowait is that needed?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Yes the same code above, I did add jm,jp,im and ip as private but still it is slow also changed DYNAMIC,chunk to STATIC

Comment: Since the innermost calculation is masked and therefore the computational load depends on the content of `rmask`, `static` might not be the optimal scheduling. But neither is `dynamic` with such chunk size.

Comment: @HristoIliev So i should not use Schedule?

Comment: @JoviDsilva, when there is some computational imbalance, `dynamic` scheduling helps. But in your case you set the chunk size to be `#iterations/#threads` which means that each thread gets the same-sized iteration chunk. The same is true for `static` scheduling with default chunk size. Without any scheduling specification most OMP runtimes default to `static` (though not guaranteed by the standard). You could still use dynamic, but use smaller chunk size, otherwise it makes little to no sense. Choosing the correct chunk size is a bit tricky and might require experimenting.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thanks I will try with a small chunksize, in the loop jmax=236 so a chunk size of 20 is it ok?

Comment: First make sure you corrected the main errors. Otherwise play with the chunk size as you wish and see the result, we have no crystal ball. Be able to see the corrected version of the code might help.

Comment: I don't understand why your are using so many OMP options... NOWAIT for instance is of course useless in your example. The only one I always use is DEFAULT(NONE) which is especially interesting in detecting immediately the trouble with the variables im and ip

Comment: @VladimirF I have added the modified code, i have tried static with not much effect. But i did see the iterations being divided uniformly. I am trying with DYNAMIC as wel.

Comment: Please, use some indentation for god's sake!

Comment: To increase the scalability, try collapse(2) to merge together the two loops